# android sdk image hot spot?

Tags: android, imagemap

I would like to know if it is possible to make a hot spot or image mapping in Android SDK. almost like you would in adobe flash or dream weaver. this information would be really helpful seeing as the buttons I got keep moving into different spots of the phone and on every device I try it on or in landscape mode all the buttons and texts is messed up. any help would be awesome.
Thanks
-Christian

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the shape of your buttons?  Or you are having trouble creating a layout where the buttons appear in the correct location?  If the latter, show us your layout.

Comment: What is a hot spot? Are you trying to just keep the buttons aligned with a certain edge or aligning to another view? Please explain what your trying to do a bit more :)

Comment: @Dory a hot spot is a section on a bitmap image or jpeg that is chosen as a section as a button from picking.

Comment: If your using flexible layouts the views should also be able to display correctly on rotation. Look into the android:gravity and android:layout_gravity attributes of Views and ViewGroups; these come in useful for implementing a layout that does not mess up on different screens and so on. Also specifying dimenions in dips rather that px is a good start!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure.. you are aware that you can turn off rotation with

```
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file. If you want both orientations you can specify separate layouts to regain full placement control as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) - see the yellow box on the right, 3/4 of the way down the page; google its terms for examples.

When you say "hot spot .. like in Flash" I hear Android's [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), perhaps with an image (slice) on it.  Such is easy to create in an XML layout.. google Android Button Background Image or similar.